# How to for loop in one JSON file to retrieve data in many dictionaries

Tags: python, json

i have this weather app i made.
I have two problem with.
Fist is have try my code  like this and it work well,  for the fist part. But the problem is when they have more city with the same name.  I can’t see the other one, because with this line of code i reach only the fist dictionaries.

```
'''

from tkinter import *
import requests
import json


root = Tk()
root.title("Weather app")
root.geometry("550x400")
root.configure(background="green")
var = IntVar()


def citylookup():

    try:
        api_request = requests.get(
            "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/autocomplete?apikey="
            "xxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxx" + city_search.get() + "&language=fr-FR")

        api = json.loads(api_request.content)
        localisation = api[0]["LocalizedName"]
        region_adm = api[0]["AdministrativeArea"]["ID"]
        id_key = api[0]["Key"]

        # citylabel = Label(root, text=localisation + ", " + region_adm)
        # citylabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        button = Button(root, text=localisation + ", " + region_adm, command=forecast)
        button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    except Exception as e:
        api = "Error..."

        def forecast():
            try:
                api_request2 = requests.get("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/"
                                        + id_key.get() + "?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxg&language="
                                                         "fr-FR&details=true&metric=true")

                api2 = json.loads(api_request2.content)

                temperature = api2[0]["Temperature"]["Metric"]["Value"]
                humidite = api2[0]["RelativeHumidity"]
                uvindex = api2[0]["UVIndex"]
                precipitation = api2[0]["PrecipitationSummary"]["Precipitation"]["Metric"]["Value"]
 
                mylabel = Label(root,text="Aujourd'hui il fait \n" + temperature + text + "\nL'humidité relative est de " + humidite + "%\n" + "L'index UV est de " + uvindex + "\nPrécipitation prévue " + precipitation)
                mylabel.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

            except Exception as e:
                api = "Error..."


city_search = Entry(root)
city_search.grid(row=0, column=0, stick=W+E+N+S)

city_button = Button(root, text="Ville rechercher", command=citylookup)
city_button.grid(row=0, column=1, stick=W+E+N+S)

root.mainloop()

'''
```

So i have try a  for loop in a json file. To retrieve all the city name in the dictionaries. (some city name have one, other 3, some 5 or more.)

for i in list(range(0, 10)) :
localisation = api[i][« LocalizedName »]
ect……

But with this i receive only one name and is the second in the dictionaries.
I have no idea’s of my mistake here…
SO for this fist problem i try, want wen i click on the button "citylookup" see all the city available in the dictionaries.

The second problem i have is for the command=forecast.
If i let my code like this i receive a message error( Unresolved reference "forecast")

Bit if i put my function "def forecast(): " whit no indent is ok no error for the forecast, but i receive the same message error with id_key.get()

And if i put my function over the function citylookup() : I receive a (no use of id_key) in the citylookup and a ( Unresolved reference "id_key") in the function "forecast"

and here i wan to do is wen i click in a city they show me the forecast.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the indentation of this code in the question is the same as the code you have, but I will assume that it is.

I don't see why are you defining the `forecast()` function within the scope of `except`. I'd recommend first to get this function out of there.

for example:

```
def do_get_json(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.content()
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        return json_data
    except Exception as ex:
       raise RuntimeError("Cannot load") from ex

# get city lookup json object
def citylookup(city):
    try:
        # construct the city lookup url here and pass it to do_get_json
        url = "...." + city
        json_data = json_data = do_get_json(url)
        return json_data
    except RuntimeError as ex:
       #handle exception for citylookup
# get forecast json object
def forecast(id_key):
    try:
        # construct the forecast url here and pass it to do_get_json
        url = "..." + id_key
        json_data = do_get_json(url)
        return json_data
    except RuntimeError as ex:
       #handle exception for forecast
.
.
.
```

This way both functions are viaible to the whole file and not only to a single scope.
*Your error is caused by something called **Scope**.*

After this you can simply call them then parse, loop, save it however you like.

> The trick here is that when you define **static functions**, you must use it **after** the definition.

*An example of a non static function in python looks like this:*

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # body of constructor
    def some_function(self, args):
        # body of function
```

> Notice the `self` argument. ^^

Here is an example of a better way to write your TK code:

```
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Weather app")
    root.geometry("550x400")
    root.configure(background="green")
    var = IntVar()
    
    # use a context dict to keep shared data
    context = {}
    
    city_search = Entry(root)
    city_search.grid(row=0, column=0, stick=W+E+N+S)
    
    def populate_city(context):
        city_obj = citylookup(city_search.get())[0]
        localisation = city_obj["LocalizedName"]
        region_adm = city_obj["AdministrativeArea"]["ID"]
        id_key = city_obj["Key"]
        #save to context
        context.id_key = id_key
    
        citylabel = Label(root, text=localisation + ", " + region_adm)
        citylabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    
    city_button = Button(root, text="Ville rechercher", command= lambda: populate_city(context))
    city_button.grid(row=0, column=1, stick=W+E+N+S)
    
    # this probably need more work
    def populate_forecast(context):
        # get key from context
        forcast_obj = forecast(context.id_key)
        for elem in forecast_obj:
            labels = []
            temperature = elem["Temperature"]["Metric"]["Value"]
            humidite = elem["RelativeHumidity"]
            uvindex = elem["UVIndex"]
            precipitation = elem["PrecipitationSummary"]["Precipitation"]["Metric"]["Value"]
     
            mylabel = Label(root,text="Aujourd'hui il fait \n" + temperature + text + "\nL'humidité relative est de " + humidite + "%\n" + "L'index UV est de " + uvindex + "\nPrécipitation prévue " + precipitation)
            mylabel.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
            lablels.append(mylable)
    
    button = Button(root, text=localisation + ", " + region_adm, command= lambda: populate_forecast(context))
    button.grid(row=1, column=0)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I have put the important word in bold so you could read some more about this, and not only **Copy/Paste**.

---

Topics to read about:

- Context and State.
- Functional Programing.
- Refactoring.
- Exception Handling.

Salut!.

Comment: Hi SaleemKhair, thank a lot i will check that during the week-end. Also thank for the topics to read, i'm new into programming, and self learning. I will check these Topics.  So if i understand i have to put my url with my apikey  ''' url = ("http:// xxxxxxxx" + city_search.get() + "apikey&xxxx") + city    And the same for the id_key.   For context = {} is new to me, but i think i understand, is like a container to store data that i can take/re-use later.  I think i not sure,  is for the '''button = Button(root, text=localisation + ......  the localisation and region_adm will be not defined?

Comment: Correct, I have written this code on spot so you will find a few bugs here and there, but you are right localisation and region_adm are only visible in the scope of the `pupulate_city` function.

Comment: Hi SalemmKhair, ok i have try the code you have writte on the spot and repair some bug. But i receive alway's this error message.  "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programme1\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Weather App\weather app for mel.py", line 90, in <lambda>
    city_button = Button(root, text="Ville rechercher", command=lambda: populate_city(context))

Comment: Part 2.  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Weather App\weather app for mel.py", line 57, in populate_city
    localisation = city_obj["LocalizedName"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Process finished with exit code 0
"    And i have this 3 problems that my ide tell me.   1-"byte" object is not callable",  2- " Type "dict" doesn't have expected attribute "id_key", and  3- Local variable "ex" value is not used.  So i'm a bite confuse whit...

Comment: Seems like context is empty, when the function is called.

Comment: yes it was i am thinking, but no clue for now. I still working on it.  Or maybe find another way to do it.